# Laravel router with no / , route with {slug}-something

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have the following route:

```
Route::get(
    '{slug}-lawyer-in-nepal',
    array(
        'as' => 'practise-area.detail',
        'uses' => 'PractiseAreaController@detail'
    )
);
```

It works when the slug does not contain "-", but throws 404 when has. Any solutions for this?

Comment: i found the answer. adding ->where('slug', '.*'); works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying the format of your slug using Regex might help the Router when it resolves your url.

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('{slug}-lawyer-in-nepal', [
    'as' => 'practise-area.detail',
    'uses' => 'PractiseAreaController@detail'
])->where('slug', '[\w-]{1,}[^-]');
```

You can take a look at the Laravel [Routing - Regular Expression Constraints documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) for more informations.